# monthly aggregation with custom day

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe like this,

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2022-10-01', periods=10, freq='10D') 
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=['inventory'], index=tidx)
print(data_frame)
```

Output:

```
               inventory
2022-10-01          1
2022-10-11          1
2022-10-21          1
2022-10-31          1
2022-11-10          1
2022-11-20          1
2022-11-30          1
2022-12-10          1
2022-12-20          1
2022-12-30          1
```

I want to find the sum from 23rd to the 23rd of each month. I couldn't find a way to pass the day number to resample method. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried with resample so far? By "23rd to 23rd" do you mean like october 23rd to november 23rd, november 23rd to december 23rd, etc?

Comment: yes, like you said, for example October 23rd to november 23rd, november 23rd to december 23rd, etc

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

tidx = pd.date_range('2022-10-01', periods=10, freq='10D') 
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=['inventory'], index=tidx)


data_frame.index.name = "date"
data_frame = data_frame.reset_index()
data_frame["fin_year_month"] = ""
data_frame.loc[data_frame["date"].dt.day < 23, ["fin_year_month"]] = (data_frame["date"] - timedelta(days=25)).dt.year.astype("str") + "_" + (data_frame["date"] - timedelta(days=25)).dt.month.astype("str")
data_frame.loc[data_frame["date"].dt.day >= 23, ["fin_year_month"]] = (data_frame["date"]).dt.year.astype("str") + "_" + (data_frame["date"]).dt.month.astype("str")
data_frame.groupby("fin_year_month").sum()
```

Just be careful with the number of days you subtract. For the 23 to 23 I subtract 25 and this is fine. For 30 or 31 it would be a harder problem. Number of days to subtract will depend on a particular month and would be easier to write a function that would give a "previous year-month" given a particular date

Comment: your code breaks with, `"None of [Index(['fin_year_month'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Must be different versions of Pandas. Ok, I made an update that might solve it for you. Please try again